# Unir filas duplicadas en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

necesito crear una consulta preparada actualmente utilizo

```
select restante,cajas,calidad, count(*) as total from separacion_detalles group by calidad
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se mucho sobre sql, en la columna `calidad` necesito hacer un `inner join` a la tabla calidad para que me muestre el nombre no el id.

Asi esta actualmente mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. como pueden ver las cajas no se suman ¿Como puedo hacer eso?
2. la columna restante es prácticamente lo mismo que cajas igual como puedo sumar todas las cajas?.

una idea de como debería quedar:

```
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
restante      cajas    calidad     total
-------------------------------------------
   40          40        CAL1        3
   40          40        CAL2        3
   20          20        CAL3        1
```

la idea es simplemente juntar las calidades que se repitan en una sola fila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería de la siguiente manera:

```
select restante,cajas,
SUM(cajas), /*se suma las cajas*/
ca.nombre, /*Con el alias de la tabla "calidad", llama la columna que guarda el nombre */
count(*) as total 
from separacion_detalles sd, 
     calidad ca /*asignamos un Alias a la tabla de "calidad"*/
where sd.calidad=ca.calidad  /*Se hace el enlace entre las tablas*/
group by 4; /*agrupa por la tercera columna de la consulta, que en este caso sería agrupar por la "calidad"*/
```

Comment: me muestra demasiada información que no concuerda. https://imgur.com/ldGJyGj

Comment: Perdón, falto la clausula `WHERE` para unir las tabla por su dato en común, ya edité de nuevo la respuesta.

Comment: funciona bien el join pero como calculo la suma total de las cajas? es uno de los dos puntos que puse en la pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Estoy un poco confundido con la estructura de las tablas, ¿podría poner la estructura de ambas tablas editando la pregunta?

Comment: así como se juntan las calidades en una sola fila, si te fijas en la segunda imagen que puse cada una tiene diferente número de cajas, ¿como podria juntar eso?

Comment: Haciendo un SUM a la columna que contiene los valores. Para poder realizar una suma hay que agrupar, pero en ente caso ya estamos agrupando por la calidad

Comment: y que podemos hacer? :/

Comment: ya edité la respuesta con la clausula SUM

Comment: justo como lo necesito, saludos!